# Unable to do cell Merge on sapUI5 in sap.ui5.Table.table

Tags: sapui5

I have a requirement where I have to merge duplicate cells in my sap.ui.Table.table.

I have successfully managed to merge the column headers using colSpan. I would like to know if there are rowSpan options on SAPUI5 tables.

I do not want to use sap.m.table and I would not want a matrixlayout either. Has someone tried tweaking the ui.tables please let me know it will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/mogpone/vr8y1o6z/) will be helpful to you.

**What it does**

For given cells **A** "[colno1,colno2,...]" this will:

- if between current row **CR** and previous row **PR** all columns **A** match:

  - For given cells **B** "[colno1,colno2,...]":

    - if a given cell of **CR[B]** matches corresponding cell of **PR[A]**
    - merge cell **CR[B]** with corresponding cell of **PR[B]**

```js
let jsonData = [{
  a: "1",
  b: "Column",
  c: "Column"
}, {
  a: "2",
  b: "Column n",
  c: "Column"
}, {
  a: "1",
  b: "Column s",
  c: "Column"
}, {
  a: "2",
  b: "Column",
  c: "ColumnZZZ"
}, {
  a: "2",
  b: "Column s",
  c: "Column"
}, {
  a: "2",
  b: "Column s",
  c: "Column"
}, {
  a: "2",
  b: "Column",
  c: "ColumnNNO"
}, {
  a: "Test s",
  b: "ColumnTASD",
  c: "Column"
}, {
  a: "Test s",
  b: "Column s",
  c: "Column"
}];

let jsonModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(jsonData);

let oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({
  id: "table",
  selectionMode: sap.ui.table.SelectionMode.None,
  visibleRowCount: jsonData.length,
  columns: [
    new sap.ui.table.Column({
      label: "Test",
      id: "id2",
      visible: true,
      showSortMenuEntry: false,
      template: new sap.m.Text({
        text: "{a}"
      }),
      sortProperty: "a"
    }),
    new sap.ui.table.Column({
      label: "Column",
      id: "id3",
      visible: true,
      template: new sap.m.Text({
        text: "{b}"
      })
    }),
    new sap.ui.table.Column({
      label: "Column",
      id: "id4",
      visible: true,
      template: new sap.m.Text({
        text: "{c}"
      })
    })
  ]
});

oTable.placeAt("content");

sap.ui.getCore().byId("table").setModel(jsonModel).bindRows("/");

var oColumn = oTable.getColumns()[0];
oTable.sort(oColumn);

// WHERE POSSIBLE //

// group by the cols "byCols"
let byCols = [0, 2];

// the cols "theCols" (if none selected, we will use all)
let theCols = [0, 1, 2];

//Aggregate columns (by cols) for similar values
oTable.onAfterRendering = function() {
  sap.ui.table.Table.prototype.onAfterRendering.apply(this, arguments);
  var aRows = oTable.getRows();
  if (aRows && aRows.length > 0) {
    let pRow;
    aRows.map((aRow, i) => {
      if (i > 0) {
        let cCells = aRow.getCells();
        let pCells = pRow.getCells();

        // if theCols is empty we use aggregation for all cells in a row
        if (theCols.length < 1) byCols = cCells.map((x, i) => i);

        if (byCols.filter(x => pCells[x].getText() == cCells[x].getText()).length == byCols.length) {
          theCols.forEach(i => {
            if (pCells[i].getText() == cCells[i].getText()) {
              $("#" + cCells[i].getId()).css("visibility", "hidden");
              $("#" + pRow.getId() + "-col" + i).css("border-bottom-style", "hidden");
            }
          });
        }

      }
      pRow = aRow;
    });
  }
};
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m, sap.ui.layout,sap.suite.ui.commons, sap.ui.commons, sap.ui.table" data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex">
</script>

<body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
  <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```